# Ajax jquery call to GET application/x-javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

How do I get content of "application/x-javascript" using jquery Ajax call? 
As it keep getting me null content.

What I am trying to use for now:

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/x-javascript;charset=utf-8",
              url:the_url, 
              async:false,
              success:function(r){ 
                console.log("el result" + r) ;
                response = r;
              }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
dataType: "json",
```

tells jQuery to ignore what the server claims it is sending back and to process the result as JSON. JavaScript isn't JSON, so this breaks it.

Remove that line.

Then you should get the data in the success function.

---

Asides:

This:

```
contentType: "application/x-javascript;charset=utf-8",
```

claims you are **sending** JavaScript. You aren't making a POST request, so you aren't sending anything. Remove it.

Even if you were sending JavaScript to the server, the `application/javascript` MIME type hasn't been experimental since 2006, so it shouldn't have the `x-` prefix on it.

---

`async:false,` is a terrible idea. It locks up the JS event loop waiting for the response. You shouldn't use it.

---

`response = r;`: assigning data to globals is usually a terrible idea. Process the data in the success event handler instead.

Comment: SO how to do the GET? as I am not posting. What would be the contentType?

Comment: You wouldn't specify any content type. You aren't making a POST request so that is no content to describe the type of. Even if you were making a POST request, the jQuery defaults for the content-type are usually correct.

Comment: So it should work that way: 
         $.ajax({
              url:login_url, 
              method: "GET",
              success:function(r){ 
                console.log("el result" + r) ;
              }


          });

? It is not working :/

Comment: Then something else is wrong but there isn't enough information in the question to tell what. Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: It works with no error, Just it results with null response. Although using the url myself in the browsers get a response.

Comment: Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: When I test it, [it works](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/28394297/) (although it has the unfortunate side effect of executing the JS, but you could override by forcing jQuery to treat it as text)

Comment: the error I got, SyntaxError: Unexpected token :. I guess ajax is trying to parse it by the wrong datatype.

Comment: Or the JavaScript you are trying to read simply has errors in it.

Comment: shouldn't it be  text   as I stated?          contentType: 'text' 
Or how can I receive it as text?

Comment: `contentType` is the content you are **sending**, if you want to ignore the content-type the server is sending back you need to use `dataType`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this out :

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'my/url',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'test=mytest&test2=mytest2',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

And read the documentation, to see what each parameter is made for :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. Why should any of the various changes you made help?

Comment: Out of the question